# Elements outside bootstrap container

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am doing layout using Bootstrap. My task is to display two items outside of the container and also display borders to the end of the screen. I'm trying to put a container in a container-fluid, and assign absolute position to the elements that need to be displayed behind the container. but in this case, the width of the element is full screen, like the container-fluid parent

```css
.home__border-gray {
        box-shadow: 
          1px 0 0 0 #DCDCDC, 
          0 1px 0 0 #DCDCDC, 
          1px 1px 0 0 #DCDCDC,
          1px 0 0 0 #DCDCDC inset, 
          0 1px 0 0 #DCDCDC inset;
          -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 0 #DCDCDC, 
          0 1px 0 0 #DCDCDC, 
          1px 1px 0 0 #DCDCDC,
          1px 0 0 0 #DCDCDC inset, 
          0 1px 0 0 #DCDCDC inset;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid p-0 home__border-gray d-flex flex-row position-relative">
              <div class="h-50 home__border-gray position-absolute">1</div>
              <div class="container p-0">
                <div class="col-12 p-0 home__border-gray d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-between">
                  <div class="col-md-6 d-flex flex-column p-4 justify-content-center">
                    <h1 class="px-4">Container</h1>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
  <div class="h-50 home__border-gray position-absolute">2</div>
</div>
```

The difficulty lies in the fact that the lines outside the container must be stretched to the end of the screen.
Expected result is:
[image: expected result]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps at all but this is what I would do to recreate your expected result. I know its different from yours but maybe this might help or you can readjust your code to fit your liking.

HTML:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-items-start">
            <div class="col-2 text-right">1</div>
            <div class="col-8 text-center d-flex align-items- center">Container</div>
            <div class="col-2">1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
        div[class^="col-2"] {
            border-bottom: 2px black solid;
        }
        div[class^="col-8"] {
            height:50px;
            border-left: 2px black solid;
            border-right: 2px black solid;
            font-size: 2.5rem;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! But this is not what was expected

Comment: Did it not display for you the same as the image you posted? Or were you looking for a different solution

Comment: This way I don't keep the width of the original container